# vim: php syntax highlighting in HAML with :php filter

Tags: php, vim, syntax, haml

I'm using the `:php` HAML filter that is supplied with `haml-contrib` to write blocks of php code inside a haml file.

this allows me to write:

```
!!! 5
%html
     %body
     -# HAML code ...
     :php
         // php code ...
```

I want to hightlight the php code in vim using this [vim-tip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Different_syntax_highlighting_within_regions_of_a_file). However, the default php syntax file that is supplied with my stock vim only highlights php code that is inside `<?php` ,`?>` tags.

How can I get around this?

Note that I can get the vim-tip to work, so highlighting the following:

```
!!! 5
%html
     %body
     -# HAML code ...
     :php
         <?php
              // php code ...
         ?>
```

does work! It just creates bad HAML output (double `<?php ... ?>` tags) and doesn't reflect the simplicity I want to achieve using HAML.

Answer (score 1):

It's more along the lines that you need updated HAML syntax rules that allow vim to detect when you're going from haml->php.

Remember, there's no such thing as a "php script". There's only files which have php code blocks embedded in them, and those code blocks are delimited with `<?php ... ?>`. There's no way for vim's php rules to directly detect that you've broken into php mode, because you don't have the `<?php` to signal that.

Comment: yes, but my question is: 'How to tell vim that `:php` in a `.haml` file means that a php code block has started?'

Comment: like I said... add the rule to the haml syntax rules. you can look at how the PHP highlighter can detect html/javascript contexts in php files for reference.